# Create temp_dir having multiple images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I would like to write a pytest function which will create a temporary directory and in which it ha images created using `PIL.Image.new("RGB",(128,128), color = 'white')` and pytest fixture. The directory path must be like as mentioned below:  How should I do it?

```
tests/
     ---test_data/
                 ---Test_0/
                           -image_1
                           -image_2
                 ---test_1/
                           -image_1
                           -image_2
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not difficult, it's just a bit tedious.

Comment: I tried using pathlb.path but I am not able to.I am stucked at erros

Comment: Show us your code.  "stucked at erros" doesn't tell us anything.  We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: see the code belown  @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_temp_path() -> None:
    """create required directories"""
    for i in range(2):
        img = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(128, 128), color='white')
        path_test = pathlib.Path("tests/test_data/test_").joinpath(i)
        path_test.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        img.save(path_test / 'test_'(i))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).